# What methods can I use to find the minimum of a tranverse field Ising model?

Tags: quantum-information, simulations, quantum-computer, ising-model, optimization

I am trying to solve for the minimum of the hamiltonian of the form:
$$
H = \sum_{i,j} J_{ij}q(i)q(j) + g_i\sum_i x(i)
$$

where q(i) is the operator (I + z(i))/2 and z(i) and x(i) are pauli operators acting on the $i^{th}$ qubit.

What methods can I use to solve this? I know that this can be solved using a Variational Quantum Eigensolver. But as far as my understanding goes, this would mean defining an ansatz and is at best, an approximation. Are quantum annealers equipped with applying time evolution of a hamiltonian defined in more than one basis, that is, a hamiltonian with off diagonal elements? Equivalently, can I use a quantum annealing simulator to achieve the same?

Comment: Implementation details of computational tasks are [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site: “While computational physics is on topic, we are not a programming site. If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic.”